# The correct way of storing millions of Many-To-Many relations (pivot)

Tags: mysql, database

## What I have

I have the next schema:

**users table:**

```
| id | name | ... | created_at | updated_at |
```

**groups table:**

```
| id | name | ... | created_at | updated_at |
```

**messages table:**

```
| id | text | ... | created_at | updated_at |
```

**user_messages table (Pivot):**

```
| user_id | message_id | sent_at |
```

**user_groups table (Pivot):**

```
| user_id | group_id | joined_at |
```

For now project is using only MySQL database.

## Problem

Storing Many-To-Many is traditional way and it is okey. But in this case I am a little confused.

Groups can include unlimited users and a group can send 10-1000 messages (or more) per day. For example, let's take some basic numbers (not millions what in a real life can also be): 1 group, 10000 users, 100 messages per day. The relation row count per day: `10000 x 100 = 1000000`. One million rows per day for one group, but groups count can also be thousands.

One idea that can come at once: Why do you need Pivot for messages? Answer is: The "target" sending option is required (For sending message only for x users, not for all).

## Question

My question is: "What is correct way to store this kind of data?"

Maybe I need to use other Database system or maybe this numbers are not a problem for MySQL.

Comment: Have you thought about using a NoSQL option?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen I am opened for suggestion, I haven't worked with NoSQL yet, but I have heard about Mongo. Maybe you can suggest NoSQL database which is suitable in this case?

Comment: Your current model does not allow you to send "target" messages. Also your current model does not have to store 10000 x 100 rows for your example. Your example will have: 1 row in `groups`, 10000 rows in `users` (a table you currently don't have), 10000 rows in `group_users`, 100 rows in `messages` and 100 rows in `group_messages`. 300 more messages will require 300 + 300 rows. To send "target" messages, add a user_id-column for that in `group_messages` (or treat individuals as a single-man-group), it will then only require n rows for n explicit targets.

Comment: @Solarflare You are right, I am sorry I have fixed schema in the post which I actually have.

Comment: Well, now your `user_messages`-table is wrong (it does not contain a `message_id`). Anyway, the point was: your last model was fine, apart from not being able to send single target messages. Instead of adding that by treating group messages as 10000 targetted messages, treat targetted messages as group messages to groups of 1 user. Then both a message to a 10000 user group and 1 user will have 1 row each. Apart from that: currently, a user cannot leave a group (and if he can, he might not be able to rejoin depending on your key). Just in case you need it.

Comment: If you WANT to save 10000 message-rows for a message to a 10000 user group, you should, as Tim proposed, use NoSQL, because there it is the prefered model. It depends on other factors/requirements. But if your only concern was the 10000 rows/message message-user-table in MySQL, you can, as described, prevent that.